# how to fix a bad source file error in Java?

Tags: java

These are my codes:

```
public class Solution {

    public boolean isBalanced(String s) {
      Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
        
        char c;
        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            c = s.charAt(i);
            if(c == '[' || c == '(') {
                stack.push(c);
            }
            
            else if(c == ']' || c == ')'){
                if(stack.isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                }
                
                else if(c == ']' && stack.peek() == '[') {
                    stack.pop();}
                else if(c == ')' && stack.peek() == '(') {
                    stack.pop();
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            if (stack.isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }   
            }
            
            }
        
        return false;
  }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        System.out.println(solution.isBalanced("()")); // should be true
        System.out.println(solution.isBalanced("(")); // should be false
        System.out.println(solution.isBalanced("(])")); // should be false

    }

}
```

and I am getting this error:

```java
Solution.java:4: error: duplicate class: a22629.Solution
public class Solution {
^

MyTests.java:6: error: cannot access Solution
Solution solution;
^

bad source file: ./Solution.java
file does not contain class Solution
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
2 errors
Not compiled
```

This is the full error I am getting and I am not sure why.

When I compile it in terminal it works, but when I want to submit it to my class portal, it does not work and gives me this error.

Comment: Make sure you don't have the package statement in your java file when submitting. I suspect this may be your issue.

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Comment: Can you list the contents of the directory on the portal? Is it like a website or SSH/SFTP session? My best guess is that there's a second class called Solution somewhere, I'm guessing in the `a22629` package? Maybe another student's?

Answer (score 0):

Please share more code Or add the command line data of your successful compilation and invocation.

### Possible Causes

1. You have `default` access scope for your class. Ensure that your class is `public` to be accessible to other's outside of your package. (Though locally you can still compile and run the class independently, other classes outside of your package can not access your class)
2. Check the package structure expected by the Test